# D3 - Add space between internal bars

Tags: d3.js

I have a demo [here](https://jsbin.com/nicecawezi/edit?html,css,js,output)

It's a simple d3 chart.

It has no space between the bars. I know I can add this with

`const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    //.padding(0.1)`

This would add space on either side of each bar.

How can I remove the space from the first and last bars so the first and last bars site up against the edge of the chart

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.paddingInner([0.1]);` for just setting the inner padding as in the documents https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#band_paddingInner

Here is the working solution:

```js
var originalData = [
 {
  date: "Jan",
  value: 1507
  },
 {
  date: "Feb",
  value: 1600
 },
 {
  date: "Mar",
  value: 1281
 },
 {
  date: "Apr",
  value: 1898
 },
 {
  date: "May",
  value: 1749
 },
 {
  date: "June",
  value: 1270
 },
 {
  date: "July",
  value: 1712
 },
 {
  date: "Aug",
  value: 1270
 },
 {
  date: "Sept",
  value: 1257
 },
 {
  date: "Oct",
  value: 1257
 },
 {
  date: "Nov",
  value: 1277
 },
 {
  date: "Dec",
  value: 1057
 }
]

///////////////////////////// Update function

const randomizeData = (data) =>  {
    const rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * data.length) + 2
    const newData = data.slice(0, rand)
    update(newData)
}

///////////////////////////// Create SVG

const w = 400
const h = 250

const margin = {
    top: 20,
    bottom: 40,
    left: 40,
    right: 20
}

const width = w - margin.left - margin.right
const height = h - margin.top - margin.bottom

const svg = d3.select(".chart-container").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "svg")
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h)

const chart = svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")

const x = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([0, width])
    .paddingInner([0.1]);
  
const y = d3.scaleLinear()
    .rangeRound([height, 0])

const xAxis = chart.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis-x")
const yAxis = chart.append("g").attr("class", "axis axis-y")              

///////////////////////////////// Update function

//Recalc Domains
//Redraw Axis
//Enter
//Update
//Exit

const update = (graphData) => {

    // Recalc domains based on new data
    // x is scaleBand
    x.domain(graphData.map( (d) => d.date) );

    y.domain([0, d3.max( graphData, (d) => d.value) ]);

    const u = chart.selectAll(".bar")
        .data(graphData)

    // Enter
    u.enter()
        .append("rect")
          .classed('bar', true)
          .attr('x', (d) => x(d.date) )
          .attr("y", (d) => y(d.value) )
          .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
          .attr("height", (d) => height - y(d.value) )

    // Update
    u.attr('x', (d) => x(d.date) )
        .attr("width", x.bandwidth() )
        .attr("y", (d) => y(d.value) )
        .attr("height", (d) => height - y(d.value) )

    // Exit
    u.exit()
        .remove()

     // Redraw axes based on new data
    xAxis.call(d3.axisBottom(x))
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
    yAxis.call(d3.axisLeft(y))    
}    

randomizeData(originalData);

var button = document.getElementById('btn');
button.addEventListener('click', () => randomizeData(originalData) );
```

```css
h1, h2 {
  font-family: Lato;
}

#svg{
  background-color: lightgrey;
}

.bar{
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
  fill: mediumvioletred;
}

.bar-label{
  fill: white;
}

.bar-label{
  text-anchor: end;
}

.grid line{
  stroke: #bbb;
}

.grid .tick:nth-child(4) line{
  stroke-width: 3;
  stroke: #999;
}

.divide{
  fill: lightgrey;
}

.update-btn{
  display: block;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="chart-container"></div>


<button class="update-btn" id="btn">Update</button>


<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.min.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```